# How to fetch records multiple times from same row till column is null in oracle

Tags: oracle

I need a solution to the below problem to retrieve records in oracle

Table: EMPLOYEE

```
EMPID  EMPNAME COMPANY1 COMPANY2 COMPANY3 COMPANY4 
111      AAA    TCS
222      BBB    CTS      WIPRO   
333      CCC    CGI      INFY     TECHM    GOOGLE
```

My result set should be like this:

```
111 AAA TCS
222 BBB CTS
222 BBB WIPRO
333 CCC CGI
333 CCC INFY
333 CCC TECHM
333 CCC GOOGLE
```

Kindly help solve this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select EMPID, EMPNAME, COMPANY1
  from EMPLOYEE
 where COMPANY1 is not null
union
select EMPID, EMPNAME, COMPANY2
  from EMPLOYEE
 where COMPANY2 is not null
union
select EMPID, EMPNAME, COMPANY3
  from EMPLOYEE
 where COMPANY3 is not null
union
select EMPID, EMPNAME, COMPANY4
  from EMPLOYEE
 where COMPANY4 is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Oracle 11g+ then use :

```
with tab(EMPID,EMPNAME,COMPANY1,COMPANY2,COMPANY3,COMPANY4) as (
  select 111, 'AAA', 'TCS', null, null, null from dual union all
  select 222, 'BBB', 'CTS', 'WIPRO', null, null from dual union all
  select 333, 'CCC', 'CGI', 'INFY', 'TECHM', 'GOOGLE' from dual
  )
----------------------
--- End of data
----------------------
select empid, empname, companies 
from tab
unpivot (companies for company in (COMPANY1, COMPANY2, COMPANY3, COMPANY4));
```

For older versions, use:

```
with tab(EMPID,EMPNAME,COMPANY1,COMPANY2,COMPANY3,COMPANY4) as (
  select 111, 'AAA', 'TCS', null, null, null from dual union all
  select 222, 'BBB', 'CTS', 'WIPRO', null, null from dual union all
  select 333, 'CCC', 'CGI', 'INFY', 'TECHM', 'GOOGLE' from dual
  ),
----------------------
--- End of data
----------------------
table1 as (SELECT EMPID,
                  EMPNAME,
                  DECODE(rown, 1, COMPANY1,
                               2, COMPANY2,
                               3, COMPANY3,
                               4, COMPANY4,
                              'N/A') AS companies
             FROM tab,
                  (SELECT level AS rown 
                     FROM dual 
                  CONNECT BY level <= 4))
select * 
  from table1 
 where companies is not null
 order by 1;
```

Output in both cases will be:

```
| EMPID | EMPNAME | COMPANIES |
|-------|---------|-----------|
|   111 |     AAA |       TCS |
|   222 |     BBB |       CTS |
|   222 |     BBB |     WIPRO |
|   333 |     CCC |    GOOGLE |
|   333 |     CCC |      INFY |
|   333 |     CCC |     TECHM |
|   333 |     CCC |       CGI |
```

Answer (score 0):

The fun part about writing this query is that you need to know exactly how many `companyX` columns are there. More the columns more the queries unioned together.

I would like to modify JoshL's answer a little and add the ordering part:

```
SELECT empid,
       empname,
       company1 AS company_name,
       1 AS company_number
  FROM employee
 WHERE company1 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT empid,
       empname,
       company2 AS company_name,
       2 AS company_number
  FROM employee
 WHERE company2 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT empid,
       empname,
       company3 AS company_name,
       3 AS company_number
  FROM employee
 WHERE company3 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT empid,
       empname,
       company4 AS company_name,
       4 AS company_number
  FROM employee
 WHERE company4 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY empid, company_number;
```